# Have to Update my code after my App status is 'ready to sale' in iTunes connect.

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

We developed an application in IOS platform using phone gap framework and got approved from apple through iTunes connect and now the status is 'Ready to sale'. Now I would like to update i.e modify my code as per the requirement. After Modifying, what is the process to be followed means is it necessary to resubmit the app or any other steps are there to modify the code in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary that you upload a signed build of your new version to the store. Your fixed version will have to go through the apple review process just as your current release did before.

In the meanwhile your only options are to make the currently 'ready to sale' version available to your users, or wait until the improved version is approved. As you release that version then, user can update to the new version via the store.

Note, afaik you don't have a way to force users to update to newer versions, unless you do it in the app itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to resubmit again.There is one option though, whether you want to release your updated version as soon as it gets approved or at your own(i.e when it get approved then you can make it available for sale at your own wish).